# How to validate password with atleast one numeric, one Uppercase letter and 6-20 characters?

Tags: javascript

I have added  this script to my form and its working with alpha numeric.The problem is when i click on wrong format on click function it will updated the data in database with submit button.How can i block? I need to update data with correct alert function.

```
function CheckPassword(inputtxt) {
   var passw = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20}$/;
   if (inputtxt.value.match(passw)) {
       alert('Congratulations You have successfully changed your password!..Plz Logout and signin again.');
       return true;
   } else {
       alert('Wrong Format...!')
       return false;
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="check-password-2.js"></script>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) )
    {              
        $password = $_POST['newpassword'];
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_login SET str_password='$password',status='1' where str_username='$user'");                              
    }     
?>

<body onload='document.form1.newpassword.focus()'>
    <form name="form1" action="" method="post" id="form1" onClick="CheckPassword(document.form1.newpassword)">
        <table width="388" align="center"></br>
        </<tr>
            <td align="right">Enter Username</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="username" name="username" value="<?php echo ucwords($_SESSION['username']); ?> " class="TxtBox" disabled="disabled" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <h5>Input Password and Submit [6 to 20 characters which contain at least one numeric digit, one uppercase and one lowercase letter]</h5>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">New Password</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="password" name="newpassword" class="TxtBox" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: can you use 3 different regular expressions?

Comment: @ketub regex is fine - https://www.regex101.com/r/tW4zE3/1

Comment: What event are you calling the `CheckPassword()` function from? It sounds like it needs to stop the request being made, but for some reason it isn't.

Comment: @creative use `onsubmit` instead `onclick`

Comment: You need to use `onsubmit` not `onclick`, and you need to add `return CheckPassword(....` to the event handler. You also need to fix your HTML as you have several mistakes.

Comment: @splash58 thanks,its not working.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you please edit my code?

Comment: @creative I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to use the `onsubmit` attribute of the `form`, not `onclick`. Secondly, you need to use a `return` statement within the attribute to provide the value returned by the function to the event handler to prevent or allow the form submission. You also need to fix several errors in your HTML. Try this:

```html
<body onload='document.form1.newpassword.focus()'>
    <form name="form1" action="" method="post" id="form1" onsubmit="return CheckPassword(document.form1.newpassword)">
        <table width="388" align="center"></br>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Enter Username</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="username" name="username" value="<?php echo ucwords($_SESSION['username']); ?> " class="TxtBox" disabled="disabled" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <h5>Input Password and Submit [6 to 20 characters which contain at least one numeric digit, one uppercase and one lowercase letter]</h5>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">New Password</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="password" name="newpassword" class="TxtBox" />    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <div align="center">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help